# How to set value of an element in child componet

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using child and parent component in my angular app. i want to set the value of an input element in my child component from parent component. i get the data from an api and the value i want to set in my child component is of type "HTML". How can i do it. please guide me.

Note: I am able to get the data from parent component to child component. I want to know how can i get the value in HTML Format to my child component using formControl and display it.

HTML parentComponent

```
<form[formGroup]='parentForm'>
    <childComponent [childForm]= "parentForm.controls.childForm" ></childComponent>
</form>
```

HTML childComponent

```
<form[formGroup]='childForm'>
    <div>
        <input [innerHtml] = "test" formControlName = "childttest">
    </div>
</form>
```

TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
        test1: [''],
        childForm: this.FormBuilder.group({
            childtest: ['']
        })
    });
    // data contains HTML code. i want to display only text not HTML.
    this.parentForm.controls.childForm.controls.childtest.setValue(this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare input parameter in Child component and bind in parent:

**Child TS**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() valueToBeUsedInChild: any;
}
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<childComponent [valueToBeUsedInChild]="data"></childComponent>
```

See [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Thanks. i have updated my question. I can bind the data between child and parent component. but i want to display the value of type HTML in my input field using FOrmControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use Input()decorator

```js
//Parent component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child [childData]="parentData"></child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent{
  parentData = "pass data from parent to child"
  constructor() { }
}

//Child component
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
      Say {{ childData}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() childData: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. i have updated my question. I can bind the data between child and parent component. but i want to display the value of type HTML in my input field using FOrmControl.